# How can I install 10.10's Light Themes in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, themes

As the title of the question says, how can I install the version of the light themes from Maverick in 10.04.2 64 bit? I've followed [these instructions](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/08/how-to-install-updated-light-themes-for.html) but I don't see any difference after restarting, and when running `apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine` and `apt-get install light-themes`, it only says that it's already at the newest version.

Comment: Did you try enabling backports first?

Comment: Yes, but the 10.10 version of the light themes wasn't backported to 10.04. I was also going to try installing the 10.10 gtk2-engines-murrine, but I'm worried about dependency hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, it worked very well for me: https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/ubuntu-artwork-backport.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem. It turns out that the murrine daily PPA was deleted, but someone on the Ubuntu Forums had a copy of one of the debs from June 2nd, 2011 that was made for 10.04 64bit ([debs.tar.gz > gtk2-engines-murrine_0.91.0~git201106021418~daily1~lucid1_amd64.deb](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10980087&postcount=2)). I downloaded that archive and installed the deb in it, and then I downloaded version [0.1.8.2 of the light-themes source from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/0.1.8.2). Finally, I extracted that into /usr/share/themes and everything's working!

Answer (score 0):

You can get them using [**Ubuntu Tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). See [light themes](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/source/webupd8team-light-themes/).

Or alternatively using [http://www.webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/install-ubuntu-1010-light-themes-in.html) ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/light-themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I also tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: that ppa no longer exists

Comment: I see , my bad , as I thought it is still on.