# Using 11.04 themes in 10.04?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 10.10's Light Themes in 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53031/how-can-i-install-10-10s-light-themes-in-10-04)

I like the "ambiance" theme in Ubuntu 11.04 better than the older "ambiance" theme in Ubuntu 10.04.  I have one machine at work that I'm supposed to use the 10.04, and would like to 'update' the themes package.

I tried temporarily adding the natty repository to grab the light-themes package, but Synaptics wants me to essentially reinstall all of my desktop to do that.  I assume there is a better way.

Searching around, all I've been able to find is this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1785600

which has the same question and is marked "solved", but references something I can't access.  So there appears to be some kind of simple solution, but I don't know what to do.  I've tried to grab the updated light-themes .deb package, but dpkg won't install it since it claims it breaks something called "metacity".

I'd like to learn how to manage packages better.
Can someone help me understand the appropriate way to update themes?