# How to copy themes?

Tags: 10.04, permissions, themes, clipboard

I tried to do something similar to this:
[How can I install 10.10's Light Themes in 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53031/how-can-i-install-10-10s-light-themes-in-10-04)

I installed the updated .deb, and then I took the `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/*` from a 11.04 machine and put it in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Natty/*` on my 10.04 machine.

For some reason the copying changed a bunch of permissions, and even changed the file name index.theme to Ambiance.desktop or something.  I changed that back to how it was in the previous system.

Under *System➜Preferences➜Appearances* I now see the Ambiance-Natty option ... however selecting it does absolutely nothing!  Nothing changes at all.

What is going on here?

1. Why did copying the directory (to a flash drive and back) change the persmissions and that one file name?
2. Why doesn't the theme work?  Is there a log to check error messages or something?

I obviously don't understand how themes work in Ubuntu, so some explanation/overview would be wonderful as well.

Comment: I think you will have more luck if you copy the files into this folder: ~/.themes/

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `light-themes` and `gtk-engines-murrine` packages from the Ubuntu 11.04 repo:

**gtk-engines-murrine**

---

32 bit: http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/main/g/gtk2-engines-murrine/gtk2-engines-murrine_0.98.1.1-0ubuntu3_i386.deb

64bit: http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/main/g/gtk2-engines-murrine/gtk2-engines-murrine_0.98.1.1-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb

**light-themes**

---

all: http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu//pool/main/l/light-themes/light-themes_0.1.8.13_all.deb

Hope this helps